# How to rewrite within subfolder using shared ssl url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite a url for an addon domain on a hosting account that uses shared ssl.
An example of the url in question is:

```
secure123.hostdomain.com/~username/subfolder/Page
```

I would like this url to redirect to:

```
secure123.hostdomain.com/~username/subfolder/pagename.php
```

Not matter what I read or try I cannot seem to get the htaccess to redirect correctly.

I have been trying multiple attempts:

```
RewriteRule ^Page$ pagename.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Page$ ~username/subfolder/pagename.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^~username/subfolder/Page$ ~username/subfolder/pagename.php [NC,L]
```

I even tried using a suggestion of

```
RewriteRule ^(^/+)/(^/+)/Page$ ~username/subfolder/pagename.php [NC,L]
```

No luck for me so far.

What would the correct rewriterule be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wanting something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3.php [R,NC,L]
```

That will allow you to use

```
secure123.hostdomain.com/~username/subfolder/Page
```

and then it will redirect to this

```
secure123.hostdomain.com/~username/subfolder/Page.php
```

Note that it will be an external redirect so the URL will change in the address bar. If you don't want the URL to change and it be an internal redirect, just remove the `R` on the last line so it reads `[NC,L]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see that your response should be working, however when I try this I get a 404 page: http://secure123.hostdomain.com/404.html. I think it has to do with this account being a shared server, and it reading the .htaccess from the hostdomain root instead of my shared account ~username. Am I right to assume that by this redirect the server is looking at the htaccess of the domain root intead of my shared account folder? Is there a way around this that you know?

Comment: Shared should not matter. Does the page actually exist? Just because you rewrite the URL doesn't mean it will just work with what ever you give it. The URL that it redirects to still has to actually exist. Tell me exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Is the subfolder a real folder? Is the file that is being redirected to a real file?

Comment: I was struggling with this sort of thing, and finally figured out how shared SSL works, and wrote it up an http://nevcal.com/eclectic/sharedSSL.html